# iOS 8 bar button item image color

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I am having an issue with using images for bar button items in iOS 8. The whole image takes the color of the tint applied.  I can't see the image at all - just a square area set to the color of the tint chosen.  All my other options are set to default.  I am relatively new to iOS development, so wondering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, this is the default action of the Navigation Bar. It makes the image used a neutral colour. I don't see your question but if you are looking for how to make it the colour you want to use I am not sure it can be done without cheating and using a UIImageView in there, which I have not tested on iOS7 or iOS8. It may not work. To reaffirm, you are not doing anything wrong, it is the navigations normal response.

Comment: Can you post you code?

Comment: I am using Storyboard to add the button items. And I cant post a screen shot as I don't have a 10 reputation yet. I see that a similar question has been posted before and answered.  But will have to figure out hoe to change the transparency/opacity of the image before using it.